# Hide specific row values in Ag-Grid - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, ag-grid

I have implemented Angular Ag-Grid for showing list of data.Is it possible to hide specific row values(cells).

[image]

Here i want to hide the last two cells(edit and del. icons) of the last row.
Currently I'm using the below code which works.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
   hideLastColCells()
},200);

hideLastColCells() {
   let tableRow = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-center-cols-container')[0].children;
   let lastRow = tableRow[tableRow.length - 1].children
   lastRow[lastRow.length-1].classList.add("d-none");
   lastRow[lastRow.length-2].classList.add("d-none");
}
```

But because of the timeout the user experience is not good and this is not the Angular way.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your cell renderer template in something like a `<div *ngIf="!hidden">...</div>`, then do something like this:

```js
class CellRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp {

  public hidden: boolean;

  // ...

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    // Set `this.hidden = true` if you want to hide your renderer here
    // In this case, when the row is the last one in the grid.
    // This assumes you're passing the rowData.length in the `context` object of your grid
    // in the parent component
    // e.g. `this.context = { numberOfRows: rowData.length }`
  
    this.hidden = params.rowIndex === params.context.numberOfRows - 1;
  }

  // ...

}
```

Just remember to pass the length of your `rowData` in ag-grid's `context` prop somehow